# bash how to return value based on two or more command status

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu

So in bash function, I run multiple commands or functions, and I'd like to return a value that is a combination of each of the status of the commands or functions, but this doesn't seem to work, it is always the status of the 1st command. How can I fix this?

```
function my_func {
    command_1
    local result_1=$?

    command_2
    local result_2=$?
    ......
    return $result_1 && $result_2 # <=== this does not work, it seems ignore result_2
}
```

Comment: If you really need to return 2 values and process them in a parent function/process, you can create a parsable string like `echo "$ret1 $ret2"` as the last line of `my_func`, and then call like `myRetArr=($(my_func args ....))` and examine each value with `echo ${myRetArr[1]}`, etc. Not what I would do (anymore (-; ) , but you could. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

In shell you can only return a single integer, `0` means success, anything else is a failure. If we generate a truth table of your commands:

|  | command_1 | command_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | true | true |
| 2 | true | false |
| 3 | false | true |
| 4 | false | false |

What would be the return value you want in each case? Presumably you would want to return success only when both commands succeed, but if that's the case there's no point in running `command_2` if `command_1` failed.

If this is the case, in shell all you do is:

```
command_1 && command_2
```

Comment: 1, 2. 3, 3? or should the last 3 be 4? Just a bit confusing, nice answer. Good use of a *Compound Command* rather than a *compound return* `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Outside of conditional expressions, the `&&` operator is a bash operator that combines the success status of a list of bash commands. You cannot use it to perform operations on numerical values.

The return command expects a numerical argument, in turn.

So, what you could do is

```
[[ result_1 -eq 0 && result_2 -eq 0 ]]  # logical "and" on success status
return $?                               # return result
```

The second line is optional, since a function will automatically return the last status.